# Implementing a for loop from an algorithm in c

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop

I am only learning c and I am trying to implement a for loop from an algorithm. I am so so confused in how to implement it, please see my attempt below. Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated as I am unsure, does it imply a loop within a loop. Or am I implementing the for loop correctly,

The algorithm states For all possible a = (0,z0,z1,0)

Looop From algorithm

```
   for (z0, z1) = (0x00, 0x00) to (0xff,0xff)
   h0 = somemethod( 0x02000000L ⊕ (0x00, z0,z1,0x00)) )
```

My Attempt

```
  #define WORD32 unsigned int 

    for (BYTE z = 0x00; z < 0xff; z++)
    {
        for (BYTE z1 = 0x00; z1 < 0xff; z1++)
        {
            WORD32 a = (0 << 24 | a1 << 16 | z << 8 | 0);
            WORD32 h0 = f(0x02000000L^a);
        }
    }
```

So I unsure about the loop and is the below correct

```
        h0 = somemethod( 0x02000000L ⊕ (0x00, z0,z1,0x00)) )

        WORD32 a = (0 << 24 | a1 << 16 | z << 8 | 0);
        WORD32 h0 = f(0x02000000L^a);
```

IE how i get

```
 (0x00, z0,z1,0x00)
```

**Update**

It is latter ordering: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), ..., (0, 255), (1, 0), …

It means all possible combinations - the ordering does not matter once you go through them all.

Comment: Don't define `WORD32`.  Just use the win32 type, `DWORD` which is the same thing.

Comment: Whether you should use a loop within a loop depends on what `for (z0, z1) = (0x00, 0x00) to (0xff,0xff)` means. Does that count `(0, 0)`, `(1, 1)`, `(2, 2)`, ..., `(255, 255)` or does it count `(0, 0)`, `(0, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, ..., `(0, 255)`, `(1, 0)`, ...?

Comment: The loop end condition is unclear too, you said `0x00` to `0xff` and implemented  `0x00` to `0xfe`, but note that `for (BYTE z = 0x00; z <= 0xff; z++)` would run forever.

Comment: Does the `^` in the abstract algorithm stand for `XOR` (like in C) or for something else?

Comment: Yes it stands for XOR, I have cleaned up above and added some more info, I hope I have made it clearer

Comment: `a1` is not defined.

Comment: The specification of what you are supposed to do is very much unclear. For example, it isn't obvious if you should check 0 to 0xff including or excluding the 0xff item. The key to successful engineering is to question the spec and make sure it makes sense, before you start implementing it.

Comment: I am sorry if this does not make sense or I have confused myself but I am trying to loop over all possible values for (0,z0,z1,0) where (z0, z1) comes from the range (0x00, 0x00) to (0xff,0xff). Thats my impression of it

Comment: Yes, but what does "the range (0x00, 0x00) to (0xff, 0xff)" mean (as MOehm has asked)? And if it means all possible combinations, in which order?

Comment: It is latter ordering: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), ..., (0, 255), (1, 0), …
So it means all possible combinations - the ordering does not matter so long as you go through them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should almost work, only the variable names, the boundaries (`0 <= a <= 0xff`) and the size of the loop variable need correction.

```
for (int z = 0; z <= 0xff; z++)
{ // inner loop same general approach...
}
```

Should you ever have a case where you iterate the whole range of numbers and switching to a bigger data type is not an option, a manual break condition at the end of loop can be used. For your loop with `BYTE` it could look like this

```
for (BYTE z = 0; z <= 0xff; z++)
{ // inner loop same general approach, followed by break condition...
    if (z == 0xff) break; // next increment would overflow to 0
}
```

Regarding the content of the inner loop, it can be shortened alot, because the `0x02000000` and the other values don't have any overlapping bytes. (note I write `a1` because you do, not because it makes any sense)

```
WORD32 a = (0 << 24 | a1 << 16 | z << 8 | 0);
WORD32 h0 = f(0x02000000L^a);
// vs same result
unsigned long h1 = f(0x02000000L | a1 << 16 | z << 8);
```

Even if you need to store `a` as intermediate result, `0 << X` isn't anything useful, just write `a = a1 << 16 | z << 8`.

So the whole code with correct variable names could look like

```
for (int z0 = 0; z0 <= 0xff; z0++)
{
    for (int z1 = 0; z1 <= 0xff; z1++)
    {
        unsigned long a = z0 << 16 | z1 << 8;
        unsigned long h = f(0x02000000 | a); // using | or ^ doesn't matter
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply I have updated above with the ordering of the loop

Comment: @JimboJones Yes, just write the nested inner loop like you did, but change the same things as I described for the outer loop (range and size) and don't use `a1` where you mean `z1`